# JQuery toggle menu if click outside of it hide()

Tags: jquery, html, css

my problem is the following - i need a jquery hide/show such as toggle() to hide and show a div. If i click outside of that div i need it to hide() , and if i click inside it , i want it to stay .I will have forms inside it , and i would like if click/type in them - the children of the div , the div to stay shown.

I have tried this -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dropdown-btn").click(function(){
        $(this).find("#dropdown").toggle();
    });
});
$(document).on("click", function(event){
    var $trigger = $(".dropdown-btn");
    if($trigger !== event.target && !$trigger.has(event.target).length){
        $(".dropdown").hide();
    }            
});
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p48bnyv5/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

1. First, your `$(".dropdown")` selector should be `$("#dropdown")`.
2. Second, `$(this).find("#dropdown")` will never work, as the element is a **sibling** not a child. Use the raw `$("#dropdown")` instead.
3. You then also need to check on the `click` event that you're not clicking on the button itself. I've done this by assigning `$("#dropdown-btn")[0]` to `trigger`, and then checking that it's not the target with `trigger !== event.target`. Note that the `[0]` is **required** for this to work, as you're looking to target the raw HTML element, rather than the jQuery object.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dropdown-btn").click(function() {
    $("#dropdown").toggle();
  });
  $(document).on("click", function(event) {
    var trigger = $("#dropdown-btn")[0];
    var dropdown = $("#dropdown");
    if (dropdown !== event.target && !dropdown.has(event.target).length && trigger !== event.target) {
      $("#dropdown").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#dropdown {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="dropdown-btn">Click</button>
<div id="dropdown">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: one problem spotted , if i click the paragraph inside , it works , but if i click the div itself , it hides,

Answer (score 0):

try `event.stopPropagation()`

```
 $(document).ready(function(){


$("#dropdown-btn").on('click', function(event){
 event.stopPropagation();
 $("#dropdown").toggle();


});



$(document).on("click", function(event){
event.stopPropagation();
$("#dropdown").hide();      


});


});
```